# The equations to a pair of opposite sides of a parallelogram are $x^2-5x+6=0$ and $y^2-6y+5=0$. Find the equations of its diagonals

Tags: coordinate-systems

Aside from solving this question, my main query is, how is such a situation even possible? The lines are parabolic, how can they ever be sides of a parallelogram?

Comment: $y=x^2-5x+6$ would be parabolic, but $x^2-5x+6=0$ means $x=2 $ or $x=3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=x^2−5x+6$ would be parabolic, but $x^2−5x+6=0$ means $x=2$ or $x=3$.

Perhaps this picture will help understanding:

[image]

Comment: So, to answer the question, the equation of the diagonals is $(y+4x-13) (y-4x+7)=y^2-6y-16x^2+80x-91=0$

Comment: or I would say the equation$\color\red{\text{s}}$ of the diagonals are $y=4x-7$ and $y=-4x+13$

Comment: Yes, well, we also would have said that the equations of the sides are $x=2$, $x=3$, $y=1$, and $y=5$.  ^_^ I thought it safest to answer in the same form as the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you factor the first, you get $(x-3)(x-2)=0$, which is a pair of vertical lines.  It is not a parabola.  If you factor the second, you get a pair of horizontal lines.  That makes a rectangle.

Comment: I don’t understand